How do I amke the HDMI port of my docking station work correctly?
I have a Dell UD22 docking station and I want connect to it 3 screens and avoid to use the laptop's. The 2 DP screens work with no issue using DisplayLink.
They work with both Xorg and Wayland and Ubuntu 22.04.5.
The HDMI port works funny:

Doesn't work at all with Xorg (blank screen, but recognized)
Works with Wayland, only after I unplug it and plug it back in

In both scenario, the HDMI screen shows the laptop's boot splashscreen, but right after seems to have the issue. So it seems to be connected to the OS.
Dell doesn't provide support for Linux (despite they sell it as compatible, since it actually works).
Logs from dmesg and journalctl report some warning/errors but I couldn't find anything related to HDMI.
Any solution I can try? Or logs to check?
